# Nginx Redirect hostname+location

Tags: redirect, nginx

my nginx config uses server_name _; to process all domains in a single server{} block and direct them all to the same codebase sitting in a single folder with a single index.php that sorts out the domain routing. (that's the way the web framework works with 100's of domains within a single cluster - cant change this).

One of the sites has 2 domains. One for each language, let's call them example.com and example.net. This site also has language-specific subfolders, let's call them: /com/ and /net/.

I need to create a redirect that ensures the language subfolder is only loaded on the matching domain.

eg, valid requests:

example.com/com/

example.net/net/

Any other request needs to be redirected based on the subfolder:

example.com/net/ -> example.net/net/

example.net/com/ -> example.com/com/

I cant do it with the framework because the folder contains all static files, so the router is never loaded. Can this be done in the nginx config?

Thank you

update, adding simplified version of my config:

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    server_name _;

    root /my/app/root;
    index index.php index.html;

    location / {
      try_files $uri /index.php;
    }

    #PHP
    location ~ \.php$ {
      try_files $uri = 404;
      [fastcgi stuff]
    }



    location = /favicon.ico {
      access_log off;
      log_not_found off;
    }

    location = /apple-touch-icon.png {
      access_log off; log_not_found off;
    }

    location = /apple-touch-icon-precomposed.png {
      access_log off;
      log_not_found off;
    }
}
```

Comment: `server_name _;` is usually used to block any other hostname on your machine. It should not be used for production.

Comment: This is a legacy server/app that is slowly being replaced so not too concerned...  I'm interested to know the reason though? And if there is a more suitable way to handle getting 100 domains that can change weekly into the same code folder without having to keep changing the nginx config files.

Comment: You could try [ngx_http_perl_module](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_perl_module.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it...

```
location /com/ {
  if ($host = 'www.example.net') {
    return 301 https://www.example.com$request_uri;
  }

  index index.html;
}
```

And the reverse for the other location/domain

Comment: Please don't use `if` directive in your `location` block 'cause [`if` is evil](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/tutorials/config_pitfalls/#using-if)!

Comment: read the link but i don't see any alternatives to the above solution for this particular issue. Open to suggestions if you have one. if not, then this is acceptable to me for a legacy server/app thats being replaced in due course.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you will need 1 location block per subfolder (but have not tested it):

```
location /com {
  proxy_pass http://upstream:8888/com;
  proxy_set_header Host example.com;
  proxy_pass_request_headers on;
}

location /net {
  proxy_pass http://upstream:8888/net;
  proxy_set_header Host example.net;
  proxy_pass_request_headers on;
}
```

Comment: thank you for the suggestion, im just trying to understand what this does and been reading. Am i right in understanding that this would only proxy it, not return a 301 redirect then forward the user to the correct url/path ?

Comment: My impression was that you are using nginX as a reverse proxy. If you are instead simply doing an URL rewrite - then you can still use a rewrite inside the location blocks but they again will be 1 location per subfolder

Comment: sorry for the ambiguity, I am using nginx as a server, it's pointing to an application folder on the same server to serve the files. having 1 block for each location is not a problem, as long as i retain the 1 server block. what would the location block look like for this redirect?

Comment: If you update your question with your actual `nginx.conf` it would be easier for both of us :)

Comment: Have added a simplified version of my nginx config server block